# How to compile Apple's securityd package?

Tags: macos, build, launchd

I am using OS X 10.7.3 with Xcode 4.3.2. I download and tried to build securityd package from http://opensource.apple.com/tarballs/securityd/securityd-55111.tar.gz.

However, I am getting tons of build errors relating to missing header files. So, I began downloading and compiling packages it required (like libsecurityd, libsecurity_utilities, launchd etc).

When compiling launchd, I get:

```
error: cannot read file /usr/local/include/xpc/events.defs


** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
Mig /usr/local/include/xpc/domain.defs x86_64
Mig /usr/local/include/xpc/events.defs x86_64
```

Has anyone figured out how to compile launchd and finally securityd on OS X? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A friend was able to compile an old version of securityd on OS X 10.4.3 (PPC) + Xcode 2.2 + darwinbuild 0.7.1. This solved the questions I had regarding securityd's internals.

However, he too found it impossible to compile newer versions of securityd.